# Show that R script is still running in command prompt

Tags: r

Currently, I have created a .bat file to run my R Script when I double click it. It looks like this:

```
@echo
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "C:/Rcode/Rscript.r"
PAUSE
```

Because my script takes several minutes to run, I'm hoping to find a way to create some kind of indicator, like a time ellasped or % of code completed, to display in the command prompt. Can anyone help me please? Thank you.

Comment: How about `?writeLines` to output which part of the script executing? Or you can use a progress bar from `utils` package `?utils::txtProgressBar`

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll try it out.

Comment: You could try `message`.